# Upload files not working in HTML & PHP

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I'm doing a form, and i can't retrieve the files. I can't find the error in the form. Please if someone can help me.

```
<div id="formulario" class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
    <form method="POST"  role="form" class="form-horizontal" id="iwantForm"
        action="iwant-process.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data" >

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="gender" class="col-md-5 control-label">Select Gender: </label>                    
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <select class="form-control" name="Gender">
                        <option class="selectBoxTextColor" value="female">Female</option>
                        <option class="selectBoxTextColor" value="men">Men</option></select>               
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class='col-md-5 control-label' for='first_name'>First Name:</label>
                <div class="col-md-7"><input class='form-control' type='text' name='first_name' id='first_name' required />
                </div></div>           
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class='col-md-5 control-label' for='last_name'>Last Name:</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <input class='form-control' type='text' name='last_name' id='last_name' required />
                </div>
            </div>            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class='col-md-5 control-label' for='telephone'>Telephone:</label>
                <div class="col-md-7"><input class='form-control' type='text' name='telephone' id='telephone' required /></div>
            </div>            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class='col-md-5 control-label' for='email'>Email:</label>
                <div class="col-md-7"><input class='form-control' type='text' name='email' id='email' required /></div>
            </div>            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class='col-md-5 control-label' for='address'>Address:</label>
                <div class="col-md-7"><input class='form-control' type='text' name='address' id='address' required />
                </div>
            </div>            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class='col-md-5 control-label' for='city'>City:</label>
                <div class="col-md-7"><input class='form-control' type='text' name='city' id='city' required />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class='col-md-5 control-label' for='nationality'>Nationality:</label>
                <div class="col-md-7"><input class='form-control' type='text' name='nationality' id='nationality' required />
                </div>
            </div>   
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class='col-md-5 control-label' for='nationality'>Comment:</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <textarea name="message" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>          
        </div> <!-- /.col-sm-6  -->
        <div class="col-sm-6">

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class='col-md-5 control-label' for='height'>Height:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <input class='form-control' type='text' name='height' id='height' required /></div>
                </div>          
                <div class="form-group">

                    <label class='col-md-5 control-label' for='size'>Size:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7"><input class='form-control' type='text' name='size' id='size'  /></div>
                </div>            
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class='col-md-5 control-label' for='waist'>Waist:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-7"><input class='form-control' type='text' name='waist' id='waist'  /></div>
                </div>            
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class='col-md-5 control-label' for='bust'>Bust:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-7"><input class='form-control' type='text' name='bust' id='bust'  /></div>
                </div>            
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class='col-md-5 control-label' for='hips'>Hips:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-7"><input class='form-control' type='text' name='hips' id='hips'  /></div>
                </div>            
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class='col-md-5 control-label' for='eyes'>Eyes:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-7"><input class='form-control' type='text' name='eyes' id='eyes'  /></div>
                </div>            
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class='col-md-5 control-label' for='hair'>Hair:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-7"><input class='form-control' type='text' name='hair' id='hair'  /></div>
                </div>            
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class='col-md-5 control-label' for='shoes'>Shoes:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-7"><input class='form-control' type='text' name='shoes' id='shoes'  /></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
            <hr>

                <div class="form-group file">
                    <label class='control-label' for="filesToUpload">Upload Photos <small> ( Maxium 5 photos )</small></label>
                     <input name="filesToUpload[]" id="filesToUpload" type="file" multiple />
                </div>

            </div>
        </div> <!-- /.col-sm-6  -->
        <hr>
    <input id="sendBtn" type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
```

this is the php...

```
<?php

  // require_once 'validator.php';

  $data = array();    // array to pass back data
  $post = array();


  foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
  {
    if ($key != 'submit') {
      $post[$key] = $value;
      echo $key.' - ' . $value ;
      echo '<br>';

    }
  }
```

I'm getting all fields except the files. what could it be ? what i'm doing wrong ?

this is what i'm getting.

Gender -
first_name -
last_name -
telephone -
email -
address -
city -
nationality -
message -
height -
size - 
waist - 
bust - 
hips - 
eyes - 
hair - 
shoes -

Comment: You will get files in global variable `$_FILES` and not in `$_POST`.

Answer (score 2):

You will get uploaded files & their details in global variable [$_FILES](http://www.php.net//manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) and not in `$_POST`

Comment: if ($key != 'submit') ? files array never contain this key, it's redundantly

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$var = $_FILES["name-of-the-file"]["name"];
```